# Help with induction where secrets are exchanged through phonecalls

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The following problem is supposed to be proven by induction, but I have a problem understanding how I can rewrite the information given to some sums to which I can prove it by induction.

> Every person of $n \ge 4$ people knows a secret that is not identical to someone else's. Show that $2n-4$ phone calls between these people are enough to make everyone aware of all the secrets. We assume that everyone has access to a phone and, during each conversation all the secrets that both speakers are aware of are exchanged.

I had an idea to use a variation of n-faculty, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The statement is false, and can therefore not be proved. Let consider n=2 than the theorrem says I need $2*2-4=0$ phonecalls but since the two secrets are non identical this can clearly not be the case.

Comment: Do you mean $n \ge 4$

Comment: @zen It is true for $n \ge 4$, not for $n \le 4$.

Comment: @jvdhooft you are correct and I see that you posted an answer detailing why (which I upvoted). However I was just pointing out that the statement how it is stated in the question is not provable.

Comment: @zen I edited the question to correct the OP's statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(n), n \ge 4$ be the statement that $n$ people require $2n-4$ conversations to share all their secrets.

Base case: 4 people require 4 conversations, so $P(4)$ is correct.

Induction hypothesis: Assume that $P(k)$ is correct for some integer $k \ge 4$. This means that $k$ people know all secrets after $2k-4$ conversations.

Induction step: If one extra person joins the group, it is sufficient for this person to make two calls: one to tell a random person out of $k$ people his/her secret(s) before all other $2k-4$ calls are made, and one to get to know all other secrets once all other calls have been made. As such, $2k - 4 + 2 = 2(k + 1) - 4$ conversations are required to share all secrets, and thus $P(k+1)$ is correct. Hence by mathematical induction $P(n)$ is correct for all positive integers $n \ge 4$.